Issue with API Response in Product Method, Project Freezes on Waiting for Response
I'm facing an issue with my API response in the GetProductsAsync method. The GetUsersAsync method works fine, but when I try to get products, the project freezes and the response is never received. I can see that the method is being called, but when the response is awaited, it seems like the program just hangs without progressing.
If I get the JSON data, I will do the mapping process, it is not important, but I cannot get a response.
Here is the relevant code:
public interface IUserService
{
    Task<List<User>> GetUsersAsync();
    Task<List<Product>> GetProductsAsync();
}
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public UserService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<List<User>> GetUsersAsync()
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); 
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<User>>(content);
    }
    public async Task<ApiResponse> GetProductsAsync()
    {
        // I'm getting an error in a subdata, it's not progressing.
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:7024/api/Product");
        //The project does not reach this stage and is stalled.
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); 
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ApiResponse>(content);
    }
}
// User.cs
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}

public class ApiResponse
{
    public List<Product> Data { get; set; }
    public object Errors { get; set; }
}



https://localhost:7024/api/Product
Response body:

{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Polo Yaka",
      "price": 30,
      "categoryId": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "createdDate": "2024-11-11T17:39:52.1000973"
    },
    {
      "name": "V yaka",
      "price": 30,
      "categoryId": 1,
      "id": 2,
      "createdDate": "2024-11-11T17:47:14.3504982"
    }
  ],
  "errors": null
}

